# Codeigniter order_by returns strange results

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I try and get ordered array of results in my controller like so:

```
$data1 = array();
$data1['acontentid'] = $id;
$data1['acgid']=$_POST['acgid'];
$data1['Sort'] = '0';

$data1 = $this->my_model->where('acgid', $data1['acgid'])->order_by('Sort');
```

I expect results to be ordered ascending by their integer value in my DB column called 'Sort'. However I get all matter of strange results:

```
object(Acontentgallery_model)[77]
  protected 'table_name' => string 'acontentgallery' (length=15)
  protected 'key' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'soft_deletes' => boolean false
  protected 'date_format' => string 'datetime' (length=8)
  protected 'log_user' => boolean false
  protected 'set_created' => boolean false
  protected 'set_modified' => boolean false
  protected 'before_insert' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'protect_attributes' (length=18)
  protected 'after_insert' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'before_update' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'protect_attributes' (length=18)
  protected 'after_update' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'before_find' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'after_find' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'before_delete' => 

///etc...
```

FIXED: the corrrect way to write it is:

```
$this->my_model->where('acgid', $data1['acgid'])->order_by('Sort', 'asc')->find_all();
```

I had to add `->find_all()` at the end

Answer (score 0):

'From The official Codeigniter Documentation:

```
Lets you set an ORDER BY clause. 
The first parameter contains the name of the column you would like to order by. 
The second parameter lets you set the direction of the result. 
**`Options are asc or desc, or random.`**



$this->db->order_by("title", "desc"); 

// Produces: ORDER BY title DESC
```

So it should be:

```
$data1 = $this->my_model->where('acgid', $acgid)->order_by('Sort','asc');
```

Comment: yes I am aware of the documentation and I did read this particular one. I still get those results.

Comment: @future_man edited the last paragraph a few seconds ago, still the same  resaults?

Comment: @future_man are you printing all results? That part is missing of your code where the output is, maybe you want to include it in your first post.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
 $this->db->where('acgid', $acgid)->order_by('Sort')->get('table_name')->result();
```

Comment: get() is undefined method!

Comment: @future_man are you using this extension ? if you are using this get is defined i think https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$data1 = $this->my_model->as_array()->get_by('acgid', $acgid)->order_by('Sort','asc');
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Acontentgallery_model::get_by()